# Echo variable and HTML in PHP IF statement

Tags: php, html, input, if-statement, echo

I have the following code, which works exactly as I expect it to:

```
<?php if ($a - $b < 1)
echo $text;
elseif ($a - $b >= 1)
echo $a - $b;
else
echo $a; ?>
```

However, now I also want to add a bit of HTML to the echo depending on the result of the IF statement.

```
<?php if ($a - $b < 1)
echo $text;
elseif ($a - $b >= 1)
echo $a - $b;
<input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_txt; ?>" id="button" class="button" />
else
echo $a;
<input type="button" value="<?php echo $button2_txt; ?>" id="button" class="button" /> ?>
```

When I do this, I get the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' on line 213 (line 213 is referring to the first `<input>` line in the code above).

Is there any way to include both the variables, and the HTML in the echo part of the IF statement?

Comment: Are the HTML `<input>` tags supposed to be part of the if/else chain? if so you'll also need `{}` or you'll get a syntax error at the `else`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Better formatting

```
<?php if ($a - $b < 1): ?>
  <?php echo $text ?>
<?php elseif ($a - $b >= 1): ?>
  <?php echo $a - $b ?>
  <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_txt ?>" id="button" class="button" />
<?php else: ?>
  <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button2_txt ?>" id="button" class="button" />
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php if ($a - $b < 1)
echo $text;
elseif ($a - $b >= 1)
{
echo $a - $b;
?>
<input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_txt; ?>" id="button" class="button" />
<?php
else
 {
echo $a;
?>
<input type="button" value="<?php echo $button2_txt; ?>" id="button" class="button" />
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to echo your lines of html:

```
<?php if ($a - $b < 1)
echo $text;
elseif ($a - $b >= 1)
echo $a - $b;
echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"$button_txt\" id=\"button\" class=\"button\" />";
else
echo $a;
echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"$button2_txt\" id=\"button\" class=\"button\" /> ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your php statements before you start a html code so your code should look something like this :

```
<?php if ($a - $b < 1)
echo $text;
elseif ($a - $b >= 1)
echo $a - $b;
?>
<input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_txt; ?>" id="button" class="button" />
<?php else
echo $a;
?>
<input type="button" value="<?php echo $button2_txt; ?>" id="button" class="button" /> ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP and HTML are different languages which get interpreted differently.
`<input type="button">` has no meaning inside PHP and is actually invalid.
PHP code goes between `<?php` and `?>` tags, HTML goes outside those tags or between quotes (making it a string).

A solution could be:

```
<?php

if ($a - $b < 1)
    echo $text;
elseif ($a - $b >= 1)
{
    echo $a - $b;
    echo '<input type="button" value="' . $button_txt . '" id="button" class="button" />';
}
else
{
    echo $a;
    echo '<input type="button" value="' . $button2_txt . '" id="button" class="button" />';
}

?>
```

Note that the actual HTML code is now between `'` and `'` since within PHP it is seen as regular text.
Also, I added the brackets `{` and `}`: when an `if` is followed by multiple instructions, the brackets are needed to specify the beginning and ending of the instructions that belong to the `if`. The same applies for the `else`.